# Ethernet is unstable - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ethernet, connection

Upon booting into Ubuntu 13.10 I can connect to my wired connection. It connects with no issues whatsoever and in fact it never disconnects at all. However, the connection is insanely unstable and becomes unusable when pages don't load. The connection somehow "resets" or something every few minutes and is usable for another couple of minutes until it drops out again.

I'm not sure what the problem is and I'm not sure what sort of logs or information to post in order to gain help, so please suggest any and I will respond quickly!

This is a 64-bit distribution of Ubuntu and the command `lspci | grep -i eth` returns:

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Thanks

Comment: **Can you provide more details?** 32 or 64 bit, Ethernet card/chip/driver, etc.

Comment: I'm having same issue: **13.10**, **64-bit**, and **Intel 82567V-4 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)** It is not continuous, but happens every so often. *When did this first happen?*

Comment: Mine has been continuous for a week or so now. After fresh installation it worked fine, but hasn't been working consistently for a while now. I'd say it started happening a week or two ago.

Comment: Would you describe as **unstable**, or just prone to mysterious **disconnect** and then re-connect *for no reason* ?!

Comment: It doesn't disconnect, it remains connected at all times. However, page load times sky rocket and mostly timeout.