# Unstable Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

My Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit has an unstable Ethernet connection. The problem is the same as [Ethernet is unstable - Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441380/ethernet-is-unstable-ubuntu-13-10), which remains unsolved. I don't experience the same problem on Windows.

`lspci | grep -i eth` returns

```
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet (rev a2)
```

`lshw -C network` returns

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: MCP77 Ethernet
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: a
   bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
   logical name: enp0s10
   version: a2
   serial: bc:5f:f4:75:8b:65
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:29 memory:dde7c000-dde7cfff ioport:c880(size=8) memory:dde7e400-dde7e4ff memory:dde7e000-dde7e00f
```

`ifconfig` returns

```
enp0s10: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe75:8b65  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bc:5f:f4:75:8b:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1390740  bytes 1803687734 (1.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 62396  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 769461  bytes 80947066 (80.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7924  bytes 603333 (603.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7924  bytes 603333 (603.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 100.77.151.121  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 95.79.101.254
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 82  bytes 23443 (23.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 191  bytes 22824 (22.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp3: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 100.77.243.249  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 95.79.101.254
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 29837  bytes 39654913 (39.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17319  bytes 1334389 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Using journal logs I figured my connection cuts at this moment:

```
device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
```

Comment: Look at the logs (don't post them all - that's logvomit) with `sudo journalctl -b 0 _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service`

Comment: `device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')`

`manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)`

`device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')`

`device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')`
My connection cuts at this moment

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify two things about your issue : you write that your Ethernet connection is unstable (it would be your enp0s10 network interface) and you show a log about your ppp0 interface, which is some point to point connection.
Your ifconfig surprisingly shows a ppp1 and ppp3, but no ppp0.

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214831/18-04-server-ethernet-interface-seen-w-lspci-but-missing-from-lshw-c-network/1215048#1215048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing .yaml file seems to have fixed the problem ([18.04 Server, Ethernet Interface seen w/ lspci, but missing from lshw -C network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214831/18-04-server-ethernet-interface-seen-w-lspci-but-missing-from-lshw-c-network/1215048#1215048)).
I changed enp0s7 to enp0s10 and edited the file as in the answer